# How can I send a message/notification/inbox message to all of a page's fans?

Tags: email, facebook-graph-api, notifications, messaging

Have been searching over the Graph API docs, looking for the answer to this. I have been told and now am pretty sure there is no way for *all* fan page fans/people that like it to see a message in semi-real-time. I know I could send emails to the users **if** they use the application, but other then that I don't see anyway possible. This is for my application that provides brand engagement with live events.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can post a status update to the wall and that will show up on their feed.  That is the best you can do if you haven't collected email addresses.

Comment: Yeah, I knew this was a possibility but it is for sure not the preferred one. I would like something that would cause the notification to go to someones phone/computer via Push on Mobile or if they are actively on Facebook.com/Facebook Desktop Notifications for Mac.

Comment: Spammers would love this too and Facebook users would hate this.

Comment: Yeah, but this is a controlled platform where you have to signup to use it and get into a pretty involved process to get to the point of sending invites but yeah, I see what you mean. Marking your response as the answer. Thanks